# What good libraries are there for object extraction?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I want to write a program that processes images.
If there are good algorithm libraries in object extraction that would save me a lot of work.
anybody?
are there any good libraries in image processing?
I am willing to use c++ or c# whatever has good libraries.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try out **[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)**.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your focus in image processing.

If your focus is image processing on digital camera images, I would suggest using OpenCV (as already mentioned by @ffriend). If your focus is image processing on radiological images (MRI, CT, etc.) I would suggest using [ITK](http://itk.org/%20ITK) for the processing algortihms and [VTK](http://vtk.org/) for rendering.

All those libraries are written in C++. Some have interfaces to scripting languages like python.

Hope this helps for a start!